# Break promise chain - stop the next 'then' from executing

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, promise

I am writing a registration system in Node/Express and I am trying to make use of Promises.

The issue is that I get an error message when using them:

**Error:**

> (node:64725) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2):

Is there a way to stop at a `then`?

```
auth.isRegistered(email)
.then((registered) => {
    if ( !registered ) {
        req.flash('pleaseRegister', 'Looks like you haven\'t registered. Please register first.');
        req.session.user = user;
        res.redirect('/register')
    }
})
.then(() => {
    return auth.isVerified(email);
})
.then((verified) => {
    if ( !verified ) {
        console.log('please verify');
        res.redirect('/register/verify');
    } else {
        req.login(user, err => {
            if ( err ) return next(err);
            req.session.timestamp = Date.now();
            auth.updateLastLogin(email)
            .then(() => {
                res.redirect(req.session.returnTo || '/account');
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: First, you error seems like a warning. Second, have you tried adding a `catch` call to your promise?

Comment: `if`/`else` like you do in the last `then` callback should be fine, do the same for `if (!registered)`.

Comment: Which promise is rejected, with what error? You never seem to `catch` any errors on any of the promises you create, so that seems to be expected.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following:

1. Throw a custom error, when you want to break the promise chain.
2. Check in `catch` callback that thrown error is a custom error. If so, just continue, otherwise call `next` with `error` object:

Example:

```
let getBreackChainError = () => {
  let err = new Error();
  err.name = 'BreackChainError';
  return err;
};

auth
  .isRegistered(email)
  .then(registered => {
      if (!registered) {
        req.flash('pleaseRegister', 'Looks like you haven\'t registered. Please register first.');
        req.session.user = user;
        res.redirect('/register');
        throw getBreackChainError();
      }
      return auth.isVerified(email);
  })
  .then(verified => {
      if (!verified) {
        console.log('please verify');
        res.redirect('/register/verify');
        throw getBreackChainError();
      }
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        req.login(user, err => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          }
          req.session.timestamp = Date.now();
          resolve();
        });
      });
  })
  .then(() => auth.updateLastLogin(email))
  .then(() => res.redirect(req.session.returnTo || '/account');
  .catch(err => {
    if (err.name !== 'BreackChainError') {
      next(err);
    }
  });
```

**Note.** You shouldn't mix callbacks with promises, use something one. In the example above, I *promisified* `req.login`, so now it returns a promise.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: I throw the "getBreackChainError" then node.js exits the script... I want it to stop the promise chain not exit the whole thing!

Comment: Found the problem - I was using Promise.reject rather than passing reject in through the function parameters if anyone can quickly explain why id appreciate it, if not ill create my own thread.

Answer (score 1):

**Language: JavaScript**

**For simplicity just use:-** *(in case you don't want to further process the error)*

```
throw new Error("An error occured");
```

**Example:-** *(fetch)*

```
fetch("endpoint/resource", requestOptions)
        .then(response => {
            if(response != null && response.status == 404) {
                throw new Error("RECEIVED NULL OBJECT");
            }
            return response;
        })
        .then(approvedResponse => approvedResponse.blob())
.catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score -1):

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2):
I believe this is because you do not have a way to handle the error in your initial .thens, because of this you get the above error. Its not "stopping" the .then, but handling the error correctly. you could do (err)=> {return} which would essentially "stop" it but its flow control in your application.